# how to set limit on relations data in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have some relational data in Nest.js, and I get these data with the TypeOrm query builder

```js
async find() {
        return this.landingSectionNameRepository.createQueryBuilder('landingSectionName')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('landingSectionName.landingSectionCategory', 'landingSectionCategory')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('landingSectionCategory.category', 'category')
            .getMany();
}
```

I want to set a limit for `category` data, I don't want to select all the categories data.
what should exactly I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.leftJoinAndSelect('landingSectionCategory.category', 'category', qb => {
  qb.take(limit); // Set the limit here for related categories
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.limit()` method. For example, this code will limit the results to 10 categories:

```
async find() {
  return this.landingSectionNameRepository.createQueryBuilder('landingSectionName')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('landingSectionName.landingSectionCategory', 'landingSectionCategory')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('landingSectionCategory.category', 'category')
    .limit(10)
    .getMany();
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, this block code will limit 10 landingSectionName, not 10 categories inside landingSectionCategory